# Menu Permission Error

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my Table Structure

```
require_once('../model/DBConfig.php');
$ob=new Connection();



menus
        ====
        menu_id       menu_name           menu_hyper    parent_id  
           1      Master Settings            #               0           
           2          Role                   #               0           
           3          Add Role           add_role.php        2           
           4          Staff              add_staff.php       1           


        menu_permission
        ===========

        id   staff_id       permission
        1      1              1,4,2,3
        2      2               2,3


<ul class="nav side-menu">


              <?php 

              $selquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menu_permission where staff_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
              foreach($selquery as $nquery)
                {

                  foreach(explode(",",$nquery['permission']) as $mnu)
                    {
                        $mnquery=$ob->showDataall("select * from menus where menu_id='".$mnu."' and parent_id='0' and delet='0'");
                        foreach($mnquery as $value)
                            {
                                echo '<li><a href="'.$value['menu_hyper'].'"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>' .$value['menu_name']. '</a></li>';

                            }

                    }

                }
              ?>
</ul>
```

The result is

**Master Settings**

> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in G:\xampp\htdocs\live\Billing Suryas\include\pages\menu_left_bar.php on line 44
>   **Role**
>   Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in G:\xampp\htdocs\live\Billing Suryas\include\pages\menu_left_bar.php on line 44

Here is my Function

```
public function showDataall($result) 
    {
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($result) or die("failed!");
        $q->execute();
        while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            $data[] = $r;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your class with `require_once('path/to/class');` then create an object with `$ob = new className`
Substituting in the path to the file containing your class, and the name of the class. 
If this doesn't fix it it's worth trying

```
print_r($selquery);
```

To see the content of the array or

```
var_dump($selquery);
```

To check whether it's actually an array.

You also misspelled `delete` in one of your SQL queries and numbers don't like being surrounded with ' quotes

Comment: delet is actually a field when delete a menu its value update to 1 initially the value of delet is 0

Comment: the result of `print_r($selquery);` Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [staff_id] => 1
            [permission] => 1,4,2,3
        )

)